# Edit XML saved as string in table column using SQL

Tags: sql, xml

The column named *xmlString* contains XML stored as a string. I need to check, for each value of this column, whether or not it contains a certain value for a ***tag1*** which is wrapped around a bunch of ***tag2***-s. The ***tag2***-s consist of key-value pairs (basically a dictionary item saved in each one) . I need to add a new ***tag2*** containing a new key-value pair in a ***tag1*** with a certain value.

For example, I have this:

```
<tag1 name=\"test_name\">
    <tag2 key=\"test_key\" value=\"test_value\" />
</tag1>
```

as a part of my XML, and I want to add a new ***tag2*** inside a ***tag1*** which contains ***name=\"test_name\"***, or even just ***"test_name\"*** if that is possible.

The desired outcome would look like this:

```
<tag1 name=\"test_name\">
    <tag2 key=\"test_key\" value=\"test_value\" />
    <tag2 key=\"new_key\" value=\"new_value\" />
</tag1>
```

I need to do this using SQL and basically update every row with the new **tag2** if it contains

```
<tag1 name =\"test_name\">
```

Comment: You need to specify what is your database. Each database vendor supports slightly different SQL variants.

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL Server 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long overdue answer, thought I'd post what I did so it could help someone else. I ended up using only XQuery. After checking if the element with "test_name" attribute existed I constructed a query with conditional insert statement to check whether or not the xml contains a certain value (true/false) for a similar element (tag2 with key "test_key"), setting my new element ("tag2[@key="new_key") value based on that value and inserting it at the appropriate position. The new xml was converted to string and then I updated each column with the new value.

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @max_id int
DECLARE @xml_form xml
DECLARE @string_form nvarchar(max)

SET @id = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM FormsTable)
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM FormsTable)

WHILE(@id is not NULL and @id <= @max_id)
BEGIN
    SET @xml_form = (SELECT xmlColumn FROM FormsTable WHERE id = @id)
        IF @xml_form.exist('(//tag1[@name="test_name"])') = 1
        BEGIN
            IF  @xml_form.exist('(//tag1[@name="test_name"]/tag2[@key="new_key"])') = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @xml_form.modify('
                   insert   
                   if(//tag1[@name="test_name"]/tag2[@key="test_key" and @value="true"])
                      then
                         <tag2 key ="new_key" value="true"/>                        
                      else
                         <tag2 key ="new_key" value="false"/>
                      after
                         (//tag1[@name="test_name"]/tag2[@key="test_key"])[1]
                   ')   

                SET @string_form = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @xml_form);

                UPDATE FormsTable
                SET xmlColumn = @string_form
                WHERE Id = @id  

            END
        END
    SET @id  = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM FormsTable  WHERE Id > @id)
END
```